# SSRS Column Header Alignment

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-tablix

The column header in my report is not perfectly right-aligned. Please help me to solve this issue
[Report Header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4tzzU.png)

Answer (score 0):

I think this is because it is word wrapping and leaving the space between the words on the first line. try removing the space and manually adding a line break.

Comment: thank you for the answer, value is coming from DB so it is not possible to add line break in it

Comment: do a replace on the value - = replace(firled!yourfield.value," ","<br/>") and make the placeholder markup property as html

Comment: I was going to suggest similar @Harry but one of the column headers that the OP posted has 2 spaces and I don't have time to work that out...

Comment: I append a space at the end of the value and that's works for me